# Is there a widget similar to expansiontile in which allows me to click the header as a separate button?

Tags: android, flutter

I need a navigation menu on my home page for my app. I have used ListView with ExpansionTile as children but i need the header to be a separate button and only the downward_arrow to open the expansion tile. How do i achieve this? Is there a widget here i am missing?

I did use ExpansionPanelList and ExpansionPanel but the result seems to ugly with borders on top and bottom. Is there a custom way to do this?

I also tried using the expansion tile as a trailing element for list tile but the viewport goes out of bounds.

Code for expansion tile part

```
  return Expanded(
      child: ListView(
        children: gridTiles
            .map(
              (tile) => ListTile(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                leading: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(7),
                    color: tile['color'],
                    child: Icon(
                      tile['icon'],
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
//                title: Text("Test"),
                title: ExpansionTile(
                  title: Text(
//                    tile['title'],
                  '',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("test"),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
```

Code for expansion panel part

```
 return ExpansionPanelList(
      expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
        setState(() {
            isExpanded1 = !isExpanded;
        });
      },
      children: gridTiles.map<ExpansionPanel>((tile) {
        return ExpansionPanel(
          body: Text("test body"),
          headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
            return ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.title),
              title: Text("test"),
              onTap: () => print("Test"),
            );
          },
          canTapOnHeader: true,
          isExpanded: isExpanded1,
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can, just add the widget you want as header, then only the arrow will open the tile and you can handle the action on your widget as you want, example with `FlatButton`

```
ExpansionTile(
          title: FlatButton(
            child: Text('Button'),
            onPressed: () {
              // clicking the button will trigger this and not open the list tile
              // only the arrow will open it 
              print('button got clicked');
            },
          ),
```